# Read RabbitMQ from Beam/DataFlow

Tags: rabbitmq, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to run a RabbitMQ queue from beam/dataflow in a streaming fashion (so that it keeps running indefinitely.)

The Minimal example code i'm trying to run is:

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.rabbitmq.RabbitMqIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.rabbitmq.RabbitMqMessage;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;

public class RabbitMqTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();
        final String serverUri = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672";

        pipeline
                .apply("Read RabbitMQ message", RabbitMqIO.read().withUri(serverUri).withQueue("my_queue"))
                .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<RabbitMqMessage, String>() {

                    @ProcessElement
                    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                        String message = new String(c.element().getBody());
                        System.out.println();
                        c.output(message);
                    }
                }));
        pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish();
    }
}
```

However it crashes with:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.UnboundedReadEvaluatorFactory$UnboundedReadEvaluator.processElement(UnboundedReadEvaluatorFactory.java:169)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.processElements(DirectTransformExecutor.java:160)
at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.run(DirectTransformExecutor.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If I don't pass in a `withMaxReadTime()` to RabbitMqIO.
If I do pass in a `withMaxReadTime()` it blocks for X seconds, then process any messages arrived during that time and then quits.

How do I set up a streaming flow that keeps running from RabbitMQ indefinitely?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue with Dataflow pipeline. When tried to run it in Dataflow I got:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WindmillTimeUtils.harnessToWindmillTimestamp(WindmillTimeUtils.java:58)
            org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext.flushState(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:400)
            org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1230)
            org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:143)
            org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:967)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

They problem was `RabbitMqIO` uses timestamp from messages comming from RabbitMq e.g for watermark. It turned out messages from RabbitMq in my case didn't have timestamp set (it is not set by default in RabbitMq) and it was null. I fixed that by preparing patch for classes in Apache Beam. I made a change in `RabbitMqMessage` constructor. Now it looks like this:

```
public RabbitMqMessage(String routingKey, QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery) {
    this.routingKey = routingKey;
    body = delivery.getBody();
    contentType = delivery.getProperties().getContentType();
    contentEncoding = delivery.getProperties().getContentEncoding();
    headers = delivery.getProperties().getHeaders();
    deliveryMode = delivery.getProperties().getDeliveryMode();
    priority = delivery.getProperties().getPriority();
    correlationId = delivery.getProperties().getCorrelationId();
    replyTo = delivery.getProperties().getReplyTo();
    expiration = delivery.getProperties().getExpiration();
    messageId = delivery.getProperties().getMessageId();
    /*
      *** IMPORTANT ***
      Sometimes timestamp in RabbitMq message properties is 'null'. `RabbitMqIO` uses that value as
      watermark, when it is `null` it causes exceptions, 'null' has to be replaced with some value in this case current time
     */
    // timestamp = delivery.getProperties().getTimestamp();
    timestamp = delivery.getProperties().getTimestamp() == null ? new Date() : delivery.getProperties().getTimestamp();
    type = delivery.getProperties().getType();
    userId = delivery.getProperties().getUserId();
    appId = delivery.getProperties().getAppId();
    clusterId = delivery.getProperties().getClusterId();
}
```

and I had to change `advance()` method in `RabbitMqIO` to not use `timestamp` property which could be null:

```
@Override
    public boolean advance() throws IOException {
        try {
            QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery(1000);
            if (delivery == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (source.spec.useCorrelationId()) {
                String correlationId = delivery.getProperties().getCorrelationId();
                if (correlationId == null) {
                    throw new IOException(
                            "RabbitMqIO.Read uses message correlation ID, but received "
                                    + "message has a null correlation ID");
                }
                currentRecordId = correlationId.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            }
            long deliveryTag = delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag();
            checkpointMark.sessionIds.add(deliveryTag);

            current = new RabbitMqMessage(source.spec.routingKey(), delivery);
            /*
              *** IMPORTANT ***
              Sometimes timestamp in RabbitMq messages is 'null' stream in Dataflow fails because
              watermark is based on that value, 'null' has to be replaced with some value. `RabbitMqMessage` was changed
              to use `new Date()` in this situation and now timestamp can be taken from it
             */
            //currentTimestamp = new Instant(delivery.getProperties().getTimestamp());
            currentTimestamp = new Instant(current.getTimestamp());
            if (currentTimestamp.isBefore(checkpointMark.oldestTimestamp)) {
                checkpointMark.oldestTimestamp = currentTimestamp;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

After running my pipeline again I got this exception again in other place. This time it was caused by not set default value for `oldestTimestamp` property in `RabbitMQCheckpointMark`. I did next change and now `RabbitMQCheckpointMark` looks like this:

```
private static class RabbitMQCheckpointMark
        implements UnboundedSource.CheckpointMark, Serializable {
    transient Channel channel;
    /*
      *** IMPORTANT *** it should be initialized with some value because without it runner (e.g Dataflow) fails with 'NullPointerException'
      Example error:
        java.lang.NullPointerException
            org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.WindmillTimeUtils.harnessToWindmillTimestamp(WindmillTimeUtils.java:58)
            org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingModeExecutionContext.flushState(StreamingModeExecutionContext.java:400)
            org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1230)
            org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:143)
            org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:967)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
            java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
            java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
     */
    Instant oldestTimestamp = new Instant(Long.MIN_VALUE);
    final List<Long> sessionIds = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void finalizeCheckpoint() throws IOException {
        for (Long sessionId : sessionIds) {
            channel.basicAck(sessionId, false);
        }
        channel.txCommit();
        oldestTimestamp = Instant.now();
        sessionIds.clear();
    }
}
```

All those changes fixed my pipeline and now it works as expected. I hope you will find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the Io that has been [fixed recently](https://github.com/apache/beam/commit/967fa79aeab7a5eb91fa0ff9299e80a958acffe2#diff-7fc2a083f63fa51ca2fb4f24d45d1a87).